# How I can display outerHTML in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery. I need to display outerHTML in chrome console but I can not . So here is code.

```
var presetsContainer = $('#presets');
var deletePresetLayoutLayer = $('#delete-preset-layout-layer');
var painterContextMenuLayer = $('#painter-context-menu-layer');
var relateAreaLayer = $('#relate-area-layer');
var layoutCanvas = $('#layout-canvas');
var layoutImage = layoutCanvas.find('img');

console.log(layoutImage);
```

When I console layoutImage it shows me these array and Objects (check this image out) [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwqMT.png)

All I need to is displaying outerHTML in console (check this image out)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEgST.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by doing this:

```
var outer_html = $('<div />').append(layoutImage.clone()).html();
console.log(outer_html);
```

here is a similar question: [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)